# Installing MikTeX, missing executables when using miktexsetup

Tags: miktex, miktex2.9

I'm installing MikTeX on appveyor CI, but I get the impression that the executables like bibtex and latex are not present anymore.
The used procedure is:

- `appveyor-retry appveyor DownloadFile  https://miktex.org/download/win/miktexsetup-x64.zip`
- `7z e miktexsetup-x64.zip`
- `appveyor-retry miktexsetup.exe --local-package-repository=C:\miktex-repository --package-set=essential download`
- `miktexsetup.exe --local-package-repository=C:\miktex-repository --package-set=essential --shared install`

With `where` there was no result for these executables and I did a search over the complete C disk but couldn't find the executables either.

The impression is that the executables got missing on November 26, 2019 (but I'm not 100% sure about this).

Question:

- is there a problem in my procedure
- how can I install the missing executables

Comment: A similar issue has been reported in the past: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/443

Comment: As a workaround, it should be possible to create the executables by running `initexmf --admin --force --mklinks`

Comment: @ChristianSchenk Thanks for this information, though now I get: Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason:
  Script configuration file not found.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
  C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf_admin.log
Command exited with code 1. As the command exit with an error I cannot continue / type the log file. Any suggestions?

Comment: For me, Christian's hint on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/420) helped to track down and solve several problems when the logfiles did not contain any hint: use MicroSoft's [DebugView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) tool and start MiKTeX with the `--trace` option.

Comment: @Twonky Problem is, unfortunately, that my problem occurs on appveyor CI and I cannot start interactive sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MiKTeX problem has been solved by means of: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/443 by declaring the package miktex-misc an essential package (again).